# Python subprocess I can not import other modules

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use a python subprocess to execute a script, which interests me to be able to do an import of my project. When running in another process, I only have the typical modules, and not those of my project when doing an import. How can I get my modules imported?

Example:

**first_script.py**

```
import subprocess
from my_project.any_module import any_module

def __init__(self):
    subprocess.call(['python', 'path/to/exec/second_script.py'])
```

**second_script.py**

```
from my_project.any_module import any_module

def __init__(self):
    print any_module.argument
```

In the first script, import any_module works, in the second it does not.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Can you please give real code?

Comment: You don't run the second_script via Python. The `subprocess.call` should throw `OSError`. Did you mean `subprocess.call(['python', 'path/to/exec/second_script.py'])`?

Comment: yes, sorry. I mean subprocess.call (['python', 'path/to/exec/second_script.py'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `my_project` module needs to be in your PYTHONPATH so Python can find it. PYTHONPATH includes your current working directory, which is why it works in your first script when you run it. But when you invoke a subprocess, the cwd is different. So you need to add the path to `my_project` to PYTHONPATH and  specify PYTHONPATH explicitly with the `env` argument to `subprocess.call()`.

However, running Python code this way is awkward. Unless you have specific requirements that prevent this, I would suggest using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package instead to run Python code in a separate process.

Comment: In case the pythonpath is not defined, how can I do it? I define pythonpath by adding the current path, and I pass it to env?

Comment: You should be able to do this to simply pass on the environment of the calling process: `subprocess.call(..., env=os.environ)`.

Comment: `urllib` is a stdlib module, so it should not require PYTHONPATH to be set. If it's still not working, please open a new question with your code and error output.