# Subproccess cannot execute files with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, subprocess

I am working on some projects these days. I have created 3 executable python files in my project called,

1. `crawler.py`
2. `process_data.py`
3. `process_csv.py`

Then I have created `run.py` to execute the above three, one after one.

---

**Problem -:** when I tried to execute the `process_csv.py` file using `run.py`, it showed me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processors/process_csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

---

**Interesting point -:** But, if I tried to execute `process_csv.py` separately without using `run.py`, it was **run without any** `pandas error`.

---

**process_csv.py**

```
import pandas as pd

# my code
```

**run.py**

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['python', 'processors/process_data.py']) # this line is working fine
subprocess.run(['python ', 'processors/process_csv.py']) # error occur in this line
```

Comment: Refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561725/python-subprocess-i-can-not-import-other-modules. I hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hardly navigate through Stackoverflow, I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912830/using-subprocess-to-run-python-script-on-windows/912847#912847) that has some kind of relation to my question. I realized [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/912847/11383441) of that question; can be applied to my question also. Then I have applied some changes to my script.

**run.py**

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.run(['python', 'processors/process_data.py']) 
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "processors/process_csv.py"]).communicate()
```

This solution 100% worked for my script.